# R-devel valgrind docker Error: "package installed by an R version with different internals"

Tags: r, docker

I've been having this problem where I try to have a docker container regularly updated on docker hub built with [rocker/r-devel-san:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-devel-san/) so that I don't have to reinstall all of the packages whenever I want to check my package with valgrind.

In my docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/zkamvar/poppr-devel-docker/builds/bi9whj736xettv3nqghczj4/) The build says it passes, but the results show a lot of errors that are in this form:

```
Error : package ‘stringi’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

This package was installed with the exact same version of R as all the other packages in the container. Does anyone have an idea as to why this would happen?

Comment: What's the version of R you have installed? What's the version of the packages involved?

Comment: The version of R would be the devel version as of 10 days ago according to the [date the r-devel-san docker container was built](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-devel-san/). All the packages are freshly built from source on CRAN when the docker container is built, so they would be whatever version is on CRAN. This is what the dockerfile looks like: https://hub.docker.com/r/zkamvar/poppr-devel-docker/~/dockerfile/

Comment: I'm running into same issue here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/package-was-installed-by-an-r-version-with-different-internals-running-shiny-server-in-docker-container/10020 Did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't remember too well how it was resolved. IIRC, the problem had to do with packages that were recently updated on CRAN.